# Cannot download resources. Added EULA package on prequisites clickonce application

Tags: installation, clickonce, prerequisites

I have a click once application deployed on a web server. I also added a EULA prerequisite for my application. When I downloaded the setup installer, the EULA is getting printed, but when I click accept and it starts to download. It shows me the following error.

[image]

My publish files are stored on this path

```
C:\WebApplications\zephyr\zephyrpos\Downloads
```

[image]

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I'm sure that the files are there. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who encounters the same error. All I did was to add .bat on mime types on IIS so it can download .bat files.